# WordPress - change post's content in single.php before it's downloaded from the database

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a form in single.php, it submits data to `wp_update_post()` on the same page. The problem is, whenever single.php loads, my update function launches after The Loop is already loaded and after it has already retrieved that post from the database.

I have to refresh the page to see any changes I made with `wp_update_post()`.

This is how I update the post:

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$my_post = get_post($queried_object->ID);

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['singleedit'])) {
    $my_post->post_content = $_POST['singleedit'];
    wp_update_post($my_post);
}
```

Even if I put it just after the header it's launched after the post in question is downloaded from the DB.

**Is there a way to change post's content in single.php before it's downloaded from the database?**

EDIT: Excuse me, I realized that I wasn't clear enough. The form is for admins only, it's a wp_editor from which they can update post's content. I already managed all of the layout concerns etc. I want admins to be able to modify the content of the post they're viewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you don't want "update" actions to re-render form content.  If the user presses refresh on the page, they will get the whole "Are you sure you want to resubmit the form data?" popup.  Instead, you'd just want to redirect the user back to the single page after a successful update.  And thus, the post would be updated.  So after `wp_update_post`, just call `wp_redirect( get_the_permalink() );`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I wasn't clear enough. The form is for admins only, it's a wp_editor, from which they can update post content. I already managed all of the layout concerns etc. I want admins to be able to modify the content of the post they're viewing.

Comment: Well, the same concern about page re-render exists even if it's an admin only form.  It's considered best practice to do a redirect after a POST form submission.

Comment: Okay, you're right, I've checked the redirect and it's so fast that nobody would notice. Thank you, I am selecting your answer as correct. By the way, you just solved one of the most requested (based on my research) WordPress questions on the Internet with just one line of code :). Good job. Thank you.